# Is it better to use array look up or if elseif statments?

Tags: java, performance

I was doing a basic programming assignment for a course I'm doing. One of the tasks was to compare two ints and print something along the lines of "5 is less than 10."

Because this exercise was a review, I'm assuming the teacher was expecting an if..else if.

I used the java Integer compare method with an array constant to produce the output. I was wondering in general which approach was better (in terms of speed, memory, clarity, etc)?

Sample code

If method:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
String text;

if (a < b)
  text = "less than";
else if (a > b)
  text = "greater than";
else
  text = "equal to";

System.out.printf("%d is %s %d", a, text, b);
```

Array method:

```
final String[] COMPS = {"less than", "equal to", "greater than"};

int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int cmp = Integer.compare(a, b) + 1;

System.out.printf("%d is %s %d", a, COMPS[cmp], b)
```

Comment: Given those two specific code blocks, I'd go with the second. But that's because I shudder when I see if-else blocks without the opening a closing braces. It' is valid, and it will compile and run just fine... but it's just inviting trouble when someone needs to add a line to one of those action blocks... shudder.  Add the appropriate `{ }` braces to the first block, and I would go with it instead.

Comment: In most applications, you should favour readability over tiny differences in performance.  Readability of code translates directly into dollars, when it comes to maintaining your code in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For clarity, I would not separate out the text into a variable at all.

```
if (a < b)
  System.out.printf("%d is less than %d%n", a, b);
else if (a > b)
  System.out.printf("%d is greater than %d%n", a, b);
else
  System.out.printf("%d is equal to %d%n", a, b);
```

This also gives you more flexibility in how the sentence is structured, which might be important in other languages.

---

> int cmp = Integer.compare(a, b) + 1;

That seems quite a dangerous thing to do, as it assumes unspecified implementation details (which of course won't change, but still...)

According to the Javadoc, [Integer#compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) "returns the value 0 if x == y; *a value less than 0* if x < y; and *a value greater than 0* if x > y". There is no guarantee that it returns +1 or -1.

Comment: I would like to +1 your answer for the bit about `Integer.compare` being dangerous, and in fact incorrect.  But I am unable to do so, as I had already +1ed your answer before you added this part.

Answer (score 4):

You could of course measure this code by running it thousands or millions of times and see which one is faster. But that will only tell you which one is faster on your system with your particular version of the JVM. The winner of this test will depend on relative memory access times and the "intelligence" of the compiler and the JIT. The Java standard can make no guarantees about which approach is faster. However it is likely that the first method will be faster because it does not require memory access. Unless this code is performance-critical and the other method is faster, you should definitely choose the if-statement method for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the String method is better because you're creating only one string based on the result of comparision. Whereas the array approach will instantiate memory required to hold all the strings at once.

Comment: In both cases, all Strings are already created as literals by the compiler

Comment: @Thilo, thanks for clearing it up. But I still think array approach is not a wise choice because of the additional overheads for lookup operations. Am I right?

Comment: No, you're not.  Lookups are extremely fast.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with your IF statements for readability. Then there's the conditional (?) operator:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;
String text = (a < b) ? "less than" :  (a > b) ? "greater than" : "equal to";
System.out.printf("%d is %s %d", a, text, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can if you want, to write a code and check if there are some obvious time cost difference .In your case, I tested, they are really seem to be no difference, average of 60-100 milliseconds.

But, you should **prefer writing a readable code**, and your first sample is much more readable than the second one. And in my sense, this is "better".

And also, the second one uses the more memory since it creates an Array.